# Is this contamination, debris?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture, mammalian-cell-culture

I have been culturing SVG cell lines. This line was obtained as a live culture from another institute and was delivered by mail. After subculturing , I saw some particles, and I do not know what they are. The cells are growing well, no debris, no colour change, no foul smell. Can anybody tell me what this is?
[image]

Comment: Welcome JEME. Could you [edit] to add some details like: 1) The magnification (or at least some idea of scale), 2) Which objects are you referring to, do you mean the crinkled object in the centre of field or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It is an imperfection in your plasticware.

Comment: Is it? Assuming it's the large object in the centre of the view, it looks like it is above the focal plane but still close to focus, which would indicate something other than plasticware - perhaps debris from the plasticware, or something like a protein precipitate from FBS